# Splitting one column from same table into multiple columns in MS-Access

Tags: ms-access-2010

For example I have a DB which has following entries:

```
Item_Name |TransactionType    |Qty 
A         |Purchase           |50
A         |Sale               | 1
A         |Sale               | 2
B         |Purchase           |25
B         | Sale              | 1
B         |Sale               | 1
```

Above table is named as Entries, Now I want to write a query in `MS-Access` which will give following output?

```
Item_Name |Purchased_QTY |Sale_QTY
A         |50             | 3
B         |25             | 2
```

I want to check for each item what is the sales and purchase
Can someone help here

Answer (score 1):

You can use crosstab query. SQL text of it below. Also this can be done using IIF() functions, but crosstab is faster in design and execution.

```
TRANSFORM Sum([DataTable].Qty) AS SumOfQty
SELECT [DataTable].Item_Name
FROM DataTable
GROUP BY [DataTable].Item_Name
PIVOT [DataTable].TransactionType;
```

Comment: Please [edit] with more information. Code-only answers are [discouraged](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196187), because they contain no searchable content, and don't help future users understand the solution. We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.